# Tensorflow single-value vs. batch tensors

Tags: tensorflow

One of Tensorflow's mysteries for me is: when does a variable represent a single tensor vs. a batch? Below is an example of a network with a continuous value output (not a classifier). In the line beginning with `loss` I calculate the loss by subtracting predictions from truth values and summing the absolute values of those differences over a batch. In that line, Tensorflow inserts a batch of truth values for `truthValues_placeholder`, so `truthValues_placeholder` is a "batch" tensor, i.e. it has one entry for each item in the batch. However, the previous line calculates `prediction` as a single value (as opposed to a batch). My question: Am I correct that Tensorflow is magically changes `prediction` into a "batch tensor", so it also has one entry calculated for each item in the batch?

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    ...
    # Network layers here
    ...
    # Final layer
    prediction = tf.matmul(inputsToLastLayer, weightsOutputLayer) + biasesOutputLayer
    loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(tf.sub(prediction, truthValues_placeholder))
    ...
    global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
    ...
    sess = tf.Session()
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init)
    for step in xrange(maxSteps):
        feed_dict = fill_feed_dict(..., truthValues_placeholder,...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow behaves the same way as numpy, in that it broadcasts basic operations with individual units to the whole matrix, like

```
In [3]: np.zeros([10, 10]) - 1
Out[3]: 
array([[-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
   [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
   [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
   [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
   [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
   [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
   [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
   [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
   [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
   [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.]])
```

So, nothing really surprising. You can test your operations with NumPy first if you want to be sure.

Comment: Thanks Julius. Understood about broadcasting, but if I am broadcasting a single predicted value across a batch of truth values then I am doing something wrong. I want a batch of unique predicted values to be compared element-by-element with corresponding entries in the truth values batch, I.e. compare predictedValues[i] to truthValues[i] Does my code above do that? If not what do I need to change?

Comment: right, you are supposed to feed a batch of truth values the same size as the features batch

Comment: and you should probably use tf.reduce_mean(loss, axis=1) to have a scalar loss, because now your loss is batch_size wide

Comment: pretty sure it will just broadcast the single truth value to the set of predictions if the truth value is individual / scalar

Comment: OK, I will use `tf.reduce_mean(loss, axis=1) ` to get a scalar batch loss. But what do I need to change to produce `prediction` as a batch (vs. a single value) to fit with the batch of truth values? That is the root of my problem.

Comment: inputs should be of shape [minibatch_length, input_feature_width] ;
weights should be of shape [input_feature_width, output_width] ;
biaises should be of shape [output_width]

Comment: ie, you should feed an inputs (in the beginning) that has `minibatch_width` as it's first dimension size

Comment: something like `sess.run([train_op], feed_dict={inputs_placeholder: training_x[minibatch_width * i: minibatch_width * (i+1)], ...... other stuff......} )`